# No matching function for call to 'AnimationSet::AnimationSet()'

Tags: c++, function, call, match

I was just doing my DrawObject constructor, and keep coming across this error:

```
C:\CodeBlocks\SDLGame\DrawObject.cpp|3|error: no matching function for call to 'AnimationSet::AnimationSet()'|
C:\CodeBlocks\SDLGame\DrawObject.cpp|3|note: candidates are:|
C:\CodeBlocks\SDLGame\AnimationSet.h|9|note: AnimationSet::AnimationSet(int)|
C:\CodeBlocks\SDLGame\AnimationSet.h|9|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
C:\CodeBlocks\SDLGame\AnimationSet.h|5|note: AnimationSet::AnimationSet(const AnimationSet&)|
C:\CodeBlocks\SDLGame\AnimationSet.h|5|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
```

This is my AnimationSet:

```
class AnimationSet
{
    public:

        AnimationSet(int animationCounter);
        virtual ~AnimationSet();
        int getCurrentFrame();
        void setCurrentFrame(int currentFrame);
        int getCurrentAnimation();
        void setCurrentAnimation(int currentAnimation);

    private:

        int currentFrame;
        int curretAnimation;
        Animation* animations;
};
```

My drawObject constructor:

```
drawObject::drawObject(char* name, char* surfaceFile, int xPos, int yPos, int drawLevel, bool willMoveVar, bool isSpriteVar, int animationNumber)
{
    animationSet = new AnimationSet(animationNumber);
    name = name;
    xPos = xPos;
    yPos = yPos;
    willMoveVar = willMove;
}
```

Comment: So what does line 3 in `DrawObject.cpp` look like?

Comment: is animationSet pointer type?

Comment: the line 3 is the constructor of drawObject, and yes, animationSet is an object of the AnimationSet class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you provided doesn't show where the error is, but I'm guessing you have an `AnimationSet` member object in `drawObject`, which means, in the absence of a default constructor, you have to initialize it in the constructor initializer list.

```
drawObject::drawObject(char* name, char* surfaceFile, int xPos, int yPos, int drawLevel, bool willMoveVar, bool isSpriteVar, int animationNumber) :
animationSet(animationNumber) //I'm assuming this isn't a pointer
{
  name = name;
  xPos = xPos;
  yPos = yPos;
  willMoveVar = willMove;
}
```

Comment: correct, I have an animationSet object in it. I forgot to mention that I was trying to build animationSet (initialize it) within the constructor... so that's why it didn't work! Why doesn't it work like that?

Comment: @user1896797 because objects are initialized before entering the constructor body. So the default constructor is called (but since you don't have one, you get the error).